# MVC Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

Me podrían ayudar con lo siguiente:

Tengo dos modelos relacionados, uno Clientes y otro Ordenes, intento generar un reporte con crystal reports de las ordenes generadas, serian algo asi como cuando un cliente compra algo en una tienda, se genera una orden de compra pero esta orden contiene dentro de su modelo los datos del cliente que genero la orden, ok, intengo que al generar el reporte de esta orden, aparezcan los datos del cliente como identificación, email, direccion etc, el problema es que soy muuuuuuuyyy novato en todo el tema de MVC y mas aun en crystal report, y el reporte solo me muestra el id del cliente ¿Cómo hacer para anidar los datos del cliente en el reporte? les dejo unos datos adicionales.

mis modelos:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Consecutivo")]
    public string Consecutive{ get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo obligatorio")]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

    public int PaymentTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
}


public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public int TypeDocumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeDocument TypeDocuments { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo es obligatorio")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max 50 caracteres")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Sólo caracteres numéricos")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Nº Documento")]
    [Index("Index_Document_Customer", IsUnique =true)]
    public string Document { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo es obligatorio")]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Max 250 caracteres")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo es obligatorio")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max 50 caracteres")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Apellido")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Max 250 caracteres")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "e-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Max 250 caracteres")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Dirección")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Max 25 caracteres")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Sólo caracteres numéricos")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Teléfono")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Nombre")]
    public virtual string FullName { get{ return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); } }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

aqui el código del controller:

```
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Commit();
                    ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
                    rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Orders.rpt"));
                    rd.SetDataSource(db.Orders.Where(o=>o.OrderId == orderAux.OrderId).ToList());
                    Response.Buffer = false;
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return File(stream,"aplicattion/pdf",string.Format("{0}.pdf",orderAux.OrderId));`
```

[image: crystal reports]

aqui el resultado del reporte
[image: Resutlado del reporte en pdf, unicamente sale el id del dato ^_^]

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es simple Steven, se llama "Lazy Loading" en Entity Framework. En tu consulta a bd solo estas cargando el id del cliente, para cargar los datos referentes a Customer, debes hacer un Include en tu consulta. ejemplo:

```
rd.SetDataSource(db.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer).Where(o=>o.OrderId == orderAux.OrderId).ToList());
```

Comment: Vicente muchas gracias por contestar, ya mas o menos me quedo claro lo q me explicas en tu comentario, pero lo que no entiendo es como lo agrego en el diseñador del crystal report te paso una foto.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdrqh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdrqh.png) esta es la parte que no entiendo, en el diseñador como añadirlo si no aparece "Customer", aparecee es el "CustomerId"

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que tu problema no es tan simple. 
Yo no he conseguido hacer funcionar linq con crystal reports directamente, siempre he tenido que usar un dataset para pasar los datos de linq al crystal reports. Te explico.
Cuando tienes mas de **una tabla** en el informe, debes de añadir todas las tablas al informe. Tu ahora mismo tienes solo la tabla AgoraF_Models_Order, y tienes que añadir la tabla Customer,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esa pantalla, donde para de campos de la base de datos, dale con botón derecho del raton y "asistente de la base de datos". En la ventana que aparece debes de añadir tu clase "customer" y en vínculos decirle los campos de las tablas que están relacionados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando termines debe aparecerte algo parecido a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te das cuenta ya aparecen los campos de las tablas

El problema es que para crystal reports cada tabla pertenece a una base de datos (o conexión) distinta por lo que luego, aunque hagas lo que dice Vicente Almea,

```
rd.SetDataSource(db.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer).Where(o=>o.OrderId == orderAux.OrderId).ToList());
```

No carga los datos, O al menos a mi no me los carga.

Soluciones:

1. O te creas una vista con las tablas relacionadas que tienen los datos que quieres mostar.
2. Añade a tu proyecto un DataSet y añade todas las tablas que quieres mostrar. y luego:

i. Haces tu consulta linq:
   List orders= db.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer).Where(o=>o.OrderId == orderAux.OrderId).ToList());

ii. Cargas las tablas customer y orders del dataset con los datos del paso anterior.

iii. cr.setDataBase(tudataset)

Espero te sirva, aunque si alguien has conseguido hacer funcionar el crystal reports con linq y mas de una tabla, encantado de ver la solución, pero creo que no funciona.

Comment: Juanjo gracias por tu ayuda, yo intentaba hacer esto para generar facturas y hacer mas "sencilla" la impresion de esta para el usuario final, pero bueno la verdad me canse de tanto intentarlo con crystal reports, dure todo un dia en eso y no hubo manera, termine haciendo una partialview con todos los datos que necesitaba y con jquery converti el html en pdf, de esta forma simulé un "reporte" pues creo que quedó muy bien la verdad para el usuario esto va a ser totalmente transparente, gracias muchachos